# How to use Linq To Sql to count the idle working duration in a day?

Tags: sql-server, linq

For example, I have a Task MIS, the data is:

Id    User           Task       TaskStartTime            TaskFinishTime

1     Mike          task1      2009-07-28 09:00:00      2009-07-28 09:45:00

2     Mike          task2      2009-07-28 09:30:00      2009-07-28 09:40:00

3     Mike          task3      2009-07-28 09:50:00      2009-07-28 10:30:00

4     Mike          task4      2009-07-28 10:20:00      2009-07-28 10:30:00

5     Mike          task5      2009-07-28 10:40:00      2009-07-28 11:50:00

How can I use Linq To Sql to cout the idle Time Duration for a day such as 2009-07-28?

The result should be:

5 minutes (between task1, task2 and task3) + 10 minutes (between task4 and task5)

= 15 minutes

Comment: -1 This sounds like a homework question, and you haven't given evidence of a decent attempt at solving it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that will do the work, using Linq.  I don't know if it's in the form you were looking for, but the logic works with the data you gave us.  You ought to be able to rearrange it into the proper shape for your app.

**MODIFIED**

```
var rows = new[] { 
    new { Id =  1, Name="Mike", TaskName="task1", StartTime=DateTime.Parse("2009-07-28 09:00:00"), EndTime=DateTime.Parse("2009-07-28 09:45:00") },
    new { Id =  2, Name="Mike", TaskName="task2", StartTime=DateTime.Parse("2009-07-28 09:30:00"), EndTime=DateTime.Parse("2009-07-28 09:40:00") },
    new { Id =  3, Name="Mike", TaskName="task3", StartTime=DateTime.Parse("2009-07-28 09:50:00"), EndTime=DateTime.Parse("2009-07-28 10:30:00") },
    new { Id =  4, Name="Mike", TaskName="task4", StartTime=DateTime.Parse("2009-07-28 10:20:00"), EndTime=DateTime.Parse("2009-07-28 10:30:00") },
    new { Id =  5, Name="Mike", TaskName="task5", StartTime=DateTime.Parse("2009-07-28 10:40:00"), EndTime=DateTime.Parse("2009-07-28 11:50:00") },
        };

var ranges = rows.Select(x => new { StartTime = x.StartTime, EndTime = x.EndTime });
int rangeCount = 0;
while (ranges.Count() != rangeCount)
{
    rangeCount = ranges.Count();
    ranges = ranges.Select(x => new {
        StartTime = ranges.Where(y => (y.StartTime <= x.StartTime && y.EndTime >= x.StartTime) || (y.StartTime <= x.EndTime && y.EndTime >= x.EndTime)).Min(y => y.StartTime),
        EndTime = ranges.Where(y => (y.StartTime <= x.StartTime && y.EndTime >= x.StartTime) || (y.StartTime <= x.EndTime && y.EndTime >= x.EndTime)).Max(y => y.EndTime),
    }).Distinct().ToList();  // ToList required to avoid recursion issues
}

TimeSpan gapTime = ranges.Max(x => x.EndTime) - ranges.Min(x => x.StartTime) - new TimeSpan(ranges.Sum(x => (x.EndTime - x.StartTime).Ticks));

System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(gapTime);
```

Comment: if the task1 data is:
StartTime=2009-07-28 09:00:00
EndTime=2009-07-28 09:50:00
then the result is wrong.

Comment: I see the problem.  With the code above, you would need to recursively calculate the ranges until the ranges couldn't be reduced.  Hopefully, I'll have a better version after I can work on it again in a few hours.

Comment: My latest edit added a loop, which recursively merges the ranges until only the appropriate items are left.  This should handle whatever data you throw at it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've worked out an option that will work.

you can use this:

```
from a in Tasks
join b in Tasks on true equals true
where a.TaskStartTime < b.TaskFinishTime
where a.TaskFinishTime > b.TaskStartTime
where a.Id < b.Id
select new {
    Id = a.Id,
    User = a.User,
    Task = (a.Task + " + " + b.Task),
    TaskStartTime = (a.TaskStartTime < b.TaskStartTime ? a.TaskStartTime : b.TaskStartTime),
    TaskFinishTime = (a.TaskFinishTime > b.TaskFinishTime ? a.TaskFinishTime : b.TaskFinishTime)
 }
```

To Collapse Down Individual tasks, until there are no intersections, then just take the sum of All Time, minus the sum of time in all tasks.

Comment: if the task1 is: start=2009-07-28 09:00:00  end=2009-07-28 09:51:00  the result has something wrong.

Comment: this should turn task1 and task2 into something like:
'task1 + task2', '2009-07-28 09:00:00', '2009-07-28 09:45:00'.  It does when I try it with LINQPad.

Comment: I think if the task1 is: start=2009-07-28 09:00:00 end=2009-07-28 09:51:00 then the result should be task1 + task3 and skip task2

Answer (score 0):

Pull the interesting records into memory and process them there (by collapsing overlapping ranges into single ranges).  The collapsing task is not suitable to querying approaches, such as sql or linqtosql.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this

Suppose you have a collection of task objects:

```
public class Task
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Task { get; set; }
    public DateTime TaskStartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime TaskFinishTime { get; set; }
}

var tasks = new List<Task> ();
// Fill tasks here...

var idleTimeInMinutes =
    tasks.Last ().TaskFinishTime.Subtract (tasks.First ().TaskStartTime).Minutes
    - tasks.Sum (t => t.TaskFinishTime.Subtract (t.TaskStartTime).Minutes);
```

EDIT: Now, wait, I see tasks overlap in your example. Then what I wrote is not going to work. I'll have to think about it...